# Updating nested states in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this state which is nested and I am having difficulty in setting state.
Error:undefined is not an object (evaluating this.state.form)
My initial state is :

```
this.state={
    activePage:0,
    visible:false,
    questionType:null,
    form:{
        title:'',
        description:'',
        pages:[{
            title:'',
            description:'',
            questions:[

            ]
        }]
    }
};
```

Now every time a user clicks, I need to add more object to pages array which should be  having a title (`''`), description (`''`) and questions (empty list). I tried achieving this but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
let newForm={
     ...this.state,
     form:{
          ...this.state.form,
          pages:[
               ...this.state.form.pages,
               pageData
          ]
     }
 };
 console.log('newForm',newForm);
 this.setState({
     form:newForm
 });
```

This is how my pageData looks like

```
let pageData={
    title:'',
    description:'',
    questions:[]
};
```

Comment: "Doesn't seem to be working" - what's the *specific* issue?

Comment: undefined is not an obect (evaluating this.state.form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the entire `state` in `newForm`. Just limit it to the `form` object:

```
let newForm = {
  ...this.state.form,
  pages: [
    ...this.state.form.pages,
    pageData
  ]
};

console.log('newForm', newForm);

this.setState({
  form: newForm
});
```

Comment: Hi adiga are you interested in small JavaScript consulting jobs? More details: http://myhotpot.io/jobs. For instance ,we would like to outsource a parser for extracting gradients from background-images. Please say when you have read this, and so this comment can get deleted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you see yourself in a situation where your state is getting **complex** or **nested** it means you should be rethinking you **component structure**, I mean you should be bringing in more **granular** components to manage their own **state**.

so why not move **form** object in your state to a different component completely.

I recommend creating a separate component for form object and let the form component manage the form state.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class form extends Component {
    state = {
      form:{
            title:'',
            description:'',
            pages:[{
                title:'',
                description:'',
                questions:[

                ]
            }]
        }
    }

    render() {
    //Form content
    }
}

export default form;
```

more granular your components are more easy to manage and that's exactly the way you should be doing things in React.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.